# Access to directory denied when running ASP.Net MVC site(4.0) in release mode on IIS 7.5 (Shared Hosting)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC site that runs successfully when the compilation mode is set to true in the sites root web.config.

If the compilation mode is set to 'false' in the sites root web.config, then the CSS folder is not accessible. I am getting a HTTP 403 status code.

**Hosting details**

ASP.Net 4.0

IIS 7.5

Shared Hosting

**Response Headers from the server**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 04:49:23 GMT
Content-Length: 1233
```

What needs to be done to make the site run properly in release mode ?

Thanks in advance

Mathew

Answer (score 0):

The issue was occurring due to use of style sheets  bundling feature which I was not aware of initially .

On researching the issue I understood that when the web site is running in debug mode the bundling of style sheets does not occur . Each style sheet is requested separately.
That was why I did not face any issue when running the site in 'Debug' mode.

When the web site is running in 'Release' mode the style sheets are bundled and minified.

I had a bundle with a virtual path ~/content/admin/css which was conflicting with a physical folder /admin/css.

Changing the  virtual path ~/content/admin/css to ~/content/admin/csss resolved the issue