# Asp.net Error running in release mode vs debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When I run my asp.net application in debug it runs fine most of the time but if I switch it to Release mode I get the below error. I am not real sure why anyone have anything I can check into ?

[image]

```
System.Exception: Error getting user roles during authentication ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Kroll.Kbs.Fraud.BusinessLogic.AuthService.Contract.IAuthService.GetAuthUser(String username, AuthResponse& serviceResponse)
   at Kroll.Kbs.Fraud.BusinessLogic.AuthService.Contract.AuthServiceProxy.GetAuthUser(String username, AuthResponse& serviceResponse) in c:\dev\fraud\source\FraudBusinessLogic\AuthService.Contract\AuthServiceProxy.cs:line 84
   at Kroll.Kbs.Fraud.FraudAdministration.Global.Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\dev\fraud\source\FraudAdministration\FraudAdministrationUI\Global.asax.cs:line 71
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Does the release web config define a different authentication mode than debug?

Comment: Good question ... the web.config is the same for release and debug ... :(

Comment: Did you get the call stack of the error?

Comment: Do you have any bundles configured?  If so, this may be your problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242381/access-to-directory-denied-when-running-asp-net-mvc-site4-0-in-release-mode-on

Comment: I wish I was using Bundles but I am not ... I'll work on getting the stack trace

Comment: Does your site run under IIS? Under which user does ApplicationPool run? Does that user have read access to the file system? What kind of Authentication (Authentification?) is set in IIS? FormsAuthentication, Windows-Authentication, anonymous authentification?

Comment: I am not getting a exception that is being logged :( this is running in ASP.Net Development Server it uses Windows Auth

Comment: I added the stacktrace not sure how helpful it is. Looks like when the webservice is built in release mode it gives a access denied error I made sure I am using the same config file on debug and release on the webconfig for the webservice and the asp.net webforms website. I have no idea what the issue is